# Login form with user direction to a new form depending on role c#

Tags: c#

guys
I am trying to work on a final project for the school. The task is to create a login form that will ask user id, password, check it with table and then depending on user's role (student, admin or faculty) direct it to different form. I did try answers here, but for some reason I can't get the code working.
My login page sits there with "ready" and "running" and not doing anything. Where is my mistake? Here is my code:

```
 public partial class Login : Form
{



 public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable result = LoginDB.Login(txtUID.Text, txtpwd.Text);
        if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            string role = result.Rows[0]["UserType"].ToString();

            switch(role)
            {
                case "student":
                     Students form = new Students();
                     form.ShowDialog();
                     this.Hide();
                    break;
                case "admin":
                      Administrators frm = new Administrators();
                      frm.ShowDialog();
                      this.Hide();
                    break;
                case "faculty":
                      Faculty fom = new Faculty();
                      fom.ShowDialog();
                      this.Hide();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserID or Password", "Invalid Login");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and LoginDB code:

```
public static DataTable Login(string UserID, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = SchoolDB.Connected();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserType from Login where UserID=@id and Password=@pwd", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", UserID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Password);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: did you try putting breakpoint in visual studio ? If not put it on switch(role) line.

Comment: Is there by chance more than one user with that username/password?  What is the value of `role`?

Comment: You should definitely add breakpoints and debug as suggested by @yogihosting, and add a default to your switch and either debug.print a comment or show a messagebox indicating that there is an unexpected UserType.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are learning to be a developer then you should also learn some good practices.  One of them is that you should not catch general exceptions if you are not going to do anything with them. So either remove the try catch block in Login or change the throw ex; to throw;

Comment: @yogihosting - I don't know what is breakpoint. I have just started this course, and not very lucky with instructor either, because he has only one answer to all questions I ask "Go and google it" :(

Comment: @ KiwiPiet - Thank you for your comment. I will remember it.

Comment: Username/password combinations are unique. I have a special table for them, where there are 4 columns: Name, UserID, Password, UserType. It checks the userid/password combination fine, because if I enter wrong combination, the "else" part works giving message box "Invalid user ID". I added default in switch case with error message. Now when I run the program, it gives that error message in default, so I am guessing my mistake somewhere in select statement. Just can't figure it out.

Comment: Within Visual Studio, if you put your cursor on a line of executable code and press F9, you should see a red dot and highlight.  (This is a breakpoint.)  Now, whenever the debugger tries to execute that line of code, execution will pause (break) and you can see what line of code is about to execute (it highlights in yellow by default) and you can see the call stack, and value of variables.  You can also "step" through the code one command at a time by using F11 (and F10 to step over a method call).  These are extremely important tools for developers.  Good luck.